# What statistical test should I use in R to compare three groups

Tags: r, count-data, biostatistics

I have three sets of data, transect 1, transect 2 and transect 3. I have got bird species abundance plotted in each data group, I would like to know which statistical test should i use?

I am looking at whether there is a difference in species and species numbers between each transect, with hopefully more species found in transect 3

[image: This is how i have my raw data organised in excel].

Comment: chi-squared, perhaps?  If all you have is a raw count per transect, you could do this in the form `chisq.test(c(5, 6, 15))` for counts of 5,6, and 15 species to do a goodness-of-fit.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to r, so can I just use that line of code you've provided to perform a goodness-of-fit?

Comment: You might be looking for an ANOVA, but we can't say for sure unless you edit your question to give us more information. For instance, you could upload your plot and link to it (with just 1 rep, you probably can't embed an image). Any introductory text on R will tell you how to run an ANOVA.

Comment: I propose Kruskal–Wallis one-way analysis of variance

Comment: I attempted to take it off hold because as far as I can see this is not too broad; indeed, many similar kinds of questions have answers here, and this one is definitely answerable; the only remaining question is whether it's maybe a duplicate (I think there are more standard options for the species distribution than those suggested in comments though). However because it was migrated and then closed, the migration was rejected and it was locked by Community, so I put it back on hold under the original reason for now.

Comment: I have reopened and unlocked. The earlier rejected migration caused by the original closure will leave a closed version at SO

Answer (score -1):

I propose **Kruskal–Wallis one-way analysis of variance**. You are interested to see if the distribution for each transect (assumed independent) is statistically different, and you have three samples.

The Kruskal-Wallis model allows you rank the data, and test your null hypothesis that the three independent transect come from the identical distribution.

You may want to apply post hoc tests if the test come up with significant.